# Configuring urls.py with this regular expression

Tags: python, regex, django

I'm trying to build my first Django-powered blog, but I'm stuck in a point.

I'm trying to grab a permanent link from the URL visited in order to display a single post.

The permanent link I'm using is like that:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/20-feb-2012/a-nice-post/
```

I'd like to grab both the date and the [slug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_URL#Slug) from this URL and pass them into a view's function.

I've made this regular expression:

```
(r'^blog/(?P<day>\d{2})-/(?P<month>\w{3})-/(?P<year>\d{4})/(P?<slug>[-\w]+)/$','blog.views.single_post'),
```

In the urls.py file, but it seems it is not working.

What's wrong with this regular expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have included slashes between the day-month-year. Remove them.

```
(r'^blog/(?P<day>\d{2})-(?P<month>\w{3})-(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$','blog.views.single_post'),
```

Answer (score 1):

Without checking anything else, you have `P?` instead of `?P` in the slug part.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you have extra slashes in your regexp for example here `(?P<month>\w{3})-**/**(?P<year>\d{4})` and also you have a P? instead of ?P at the end.

In addition, I thought you might want to have a working regexp example. So I tested this one and it works for `/blog/20-feb-2012/a-nice-post/`:

```
r'^blog/(?P<day>\d{2})-(?P<month>\w{3})-(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$'
```